# Why does the formula for two successive discounts not work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Im in 8th grade and I encountered this question in my book.

```
CP = 1190
Discount on MP = 16%
Gain on SP = 20%
Find the MP
```

This means that if we do a 16% discount on MP, we get SP and if we do a 20% discount on that, we get the CP which is 1190.

That means there are two successive discounts on the MP to get to the CP. And, when there are two succesive dicounts, we use the formula "$x+y+\frac{xy}{100}$"

And implementing it here, I get "$-16-20+\frac{-20*-16}{100} = -32.8$ "

So,

$$\frac{100-32.8}{100}x = 1190$$
$$\frac{67.2}{100}x = 1190$$
$$x = 1770.8333333$$

But, the actual solution to this is 1700.

Why is this wrong? Where did I miss the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem's wording is not proper.

Instead of gain **on** S.P. they mean gain **at** S.P. or gain **on sale**

Then $1190*(1+0.2)= (1-0.16)x \Longrightarrow x = 1700$

Comment: does it not mean the same? i mean even u multiplied by 0.2 extra which account for the 20% im talking about. right?

Comment: 20% is not discount %, it is *gain* % on C.P. , this is not a case of successive discount. I have made the equation clearer by writing (1+0.2) and (1-0.16) in the equations.

Comment: Ohhhh. I get it. That 20% was not on SP. It was on CP. Thanks! +25